# Dynamic MemberExpression

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression-trees

I am wanting to create a MemberExpression knowing only the field name; eg:

```
public static Expression<Func<TModel, T>> GenerateMemberExpression<TModel, T>(string fieldName)
    {
        PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo;

        fieldPropertyInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(fieldName);

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e"); // {e}
        var columnExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParam, fieldPropertyInfo); // {e.fieldName}
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(columnExpr, entityParam) as Expression<Func<TModel, T>>; // {e => e.column}

        return lambda;
    }
```

The problem with the above is that the field type must be strongly typed. Passing "object" in as the field type doesn't work. Is there any way to generate this? Even Dynamic LINQ doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

1. The parameter to your method is called `fieldName`, but you are getting a *property* out with it.
2. You are using the non-generic `Expression.Lambda` method to generate the expression, which may choose an inappropriate delegate-type if the type-argument `T` passed to the method is not the same as the property-type. In this case, the `as` cast from the expression to the method's return-type will fail and evaluate to `null`. Solution: Use the [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336566.aspx) `Lambda` method with the appropriate type-arguments. No casting required.
3. If you solve the second issue, things will work fine when a safe reference-conversion is available from the property-type to `T`, but not when more complicated conversions such as boxing / lifting are  required. Solution: Use the [**`Expression.Convert`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx) method where necessary.

---

Here's an update to your sample that addresses these issues:

```
public static Expression<Func<TModel, T>> GenerateMemberExpression<TModel, T>
   (string propertyName)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(propertyName);

    var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e"); 
    Expression columnExpr = Expression.Property(entityParam, propertyInfo);

    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(T))
        columnExpr = Expression.Convert(columnExpr, typeof(T));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, T>>(columnExpr, entityParam);
}
```

This will make all of the following calls succeed:

```
GenerateMemberExpression<FileInfo, string>("Name");
GenerateMemberExpression<string, int>("Length");

// Reference conversion
GenerateMemberExpression<FileInfo, object>("Name");          

//Boxing conversion
GenerateMemberExpression<string, object>("Length");

//Lifted conversion
GenerateMemberExpression<string, int?>("Length");
```

Comment: Thank you @Ani. Helped me out quite a bit. For my own code I also added a method taking the propertyInfo rather than the propertyName.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your sample of code helped me understand the expression building and allowed me to do what I wanted to :D

Answer (score 2):

Try manually converting the field value in case of passing an "object". For example:

```
var columnExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParam, fieldPropertyInfo); // {e.fieldName}
if (T.GetType().Equals(typeof(object)))
{
    columnExpr = Expression.Convert(columnExpr, typeof(object));
}
```

Hope this will help you.